# Unable to print on a new window, results in blank window

Tags: c, window, ncurses

I am unable to print something on new window created by below code in c.

In output there is only blank window but "start" is not printing.

```
#include <ncurses.h>    
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int a=50,b=50;
        initscr(); curs_set(0);
        mvprintw(a,b,"start");   //this line is not working
        getch();
        endwin();
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: How tall is your window? Row 50 might be out of range.

Comment: yeah thanx so much i got it